# Build publisher policy assembly as part of an automated build

Tags: msbuild, build, build-automation, teamcity, publisher-policy

Has anyone solved the problem of automatically building publisher policy assemblies as part of an automated build? I've trawled the web and there are plenty of people asking about this but no solutions.

Constructing policy assemblies is hugely error prone when done manually and in any case needs to be part of the continuous integration build that we run in TeamCity.

I'm hoping specifically for a solution that uses MSBuild and can run on TeamCity, but I can interpolate from other solutions if necessary. Surely, someone MUST have done this?

Comment: Just came across this since I have the same question. Did you find a solution by now?